# Does Mail.app support plugins (API)?

Tags: macos, apple-mail

Does Mail.app (Mac) have an API where developers can create plugins for Mail?

I'm confused by an official **[Knowledge Base article Apple wrote](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3167)** that states:

> Apple does not support the installation or use of third-party plugins with Mail.app. Third-party Mail plugins are located in ~/Library/Mail/Bundles and /Library/Mail/Bundles.

So plugin's are located in `/Bundles`, but they are **not** supported?

I'm confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Not supported" just means literally: "We don´t care if it breaks anything, so continue at your own risk - we won´t fix or support it". There are Bundles around, and I think the best overview you can find if on the ["Hawk Wings" Website](http://www.hawkwings.net/plugins.htm).

Indeed, Apple doesn´t offer a public API, it keeps it private. [This blog entry](http://eaganj.free.fr/weblog/?post/2009/07/14/Demystifying-Mail.app-Plugins-on-Leopard) tries to explain in quite some detail how to work with that private API nevertheless, and maybe could provide a good starting point for you.

Comment: is what your saying is that Apple does not have a public API for Mail? If so, can you update your answer as such.

Comment: It appears that HawkWings.net is no longer in existence